# How to add displot to sub-histogram using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, data-visualization

I have simplified code like this:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)
axs[0].hist(x)
axs[1].hist(y)
```

and I need to add density curve to each plot. Anyone know reasonable simple way to do this? It could be using seaborn. Kindly help.

Funtion seaborn.displot() does not working in subplots.

Comment: The question in the op is _I need to add density curve to each plot._ which is provided in the accepted answer of the duplicate (the same as is shown below), as `kde=True`. So it does answer the question. The accepted answer in the duplicate shows how to add a density curve for each of the seaborn plots that produce a histogram.

Comment: You are right, I did not noticed that. Sorry, my mistake. You can close this post if you want.

Comment: Best regards, and happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**`seaborn.histplot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) and pass `kde` parameter:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)

sns.histplot(x, ax = axs[0], kde = True)
sns.histplot(y, ax = axs[1], kde = True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Works exactly like I wanted.